# Interest rate hedging using treasury futures – timing and duration

Tags: futures, hedging, duration, bond-futures

I'm pondering over the following (rather standard) problem:

> We have \$10 million invested in government bonds and are concerned with highly volatile interest rate over the next six months. We want to use the 6-month T-bond futures to protect the value of the portfolio.
>
> - Duration of the bond portfolio is 6.80 years.
> - Current futures price is 93 2/32 (for face value of \$100).
>
>   - The T-bond to be delivered has a duration of 9.20 years.
>   - Each contract delivers \$100,000 face value of bonds.
>   - Futures price for the total contract is \$93,062.50.
>   - 6-month interest rate is 4%.

Source: p. 15 of [these lecture notes](http://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Erosentha/courses/BEM103/Readings/JWCh10.pdf) [pdf] by J. Wang

My understanding of the premise: If the interest rate increases by $\Delta y$, the value of the bonds portfolio changes (up to a linear approximation) by
$$\frac{dP}{dy}\Delta y = -P\left(-\frac{1}{P}\frac{dP}{dy}\right)\Delta y = -P \times MD_P \times \Delta y = -10,000,000 \times 6.80 \times \Delta y.$$ We want to offset this by selling treasury futures.

The author now writes the following:

> Duration of the futures contract: $H = B(1+y)^{1/2}$.
> $$MD_H = MD_B + (1+y)^{-1}(1/2) = 9.20 + (1+04)^{-1}(0.5) = 9.68$$
> Match duration:
> $$(\# \text{ of contracts})(93,062.50)(9.68) = (10,000,000)(6.80)$$

The expression for the (modified) duration is not what one obtains if applying the standard formula $MD_H = -\frac{1}{H}\frac{dH}{dy}$ to the expression $H = B(1+y)^{1/2}$. However it *is* obtained if applying the formula to the expression $B(1+y)^{-1/2}$, which could be interpreted as the present value of a bond worth $B$ in 6 months – but that's hardly the futures price. I think the issue comes down to the author being sloppy with timing and notation, and not separating the futures price from the value of holding a futures contract.

Would someone care to explain the author's thinking here? To what expression are we applying the formula for the modified duration, and why?

Ideally, I would also like a heuristic argument along the lines of "When the interest rate increases by $\Delta y$, the value of being short in the futures contract changes by ..." in order to provide some intuition for the solution.

Thanks!